# facebook and PHP. How to add unique like buttons?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-like

I have a table list of products generated in PHP.

The list contains: `title | description | price | like_button`

the Like button that I use is:

```
<iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?app_id=103750869718158&amp;href= echo "http://'.$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"].'; &amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=100&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font=arial&amp;height=21" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:100px; height:21px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

The list gets generated with, lets say 20 products and respectively 20 likes.

The problem occurs when I click on one Like button, all other like buttons get activated and I would like them to be independent one from each other.

[here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ed5vJeaEuzA&feature=player_embedded) is an idea

All help or ideas are appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: Your posted code doesn't quite make sense (I see a stray `echo` in the `src` tag for the iframe, for instance)...

Comment: Pretty sure you need a seperate button for each one.

Comment: @Brian - See his question subject. I think the OP is aware of this... ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the page you're using as an example (not a marketing video of the page, [but the actual page itself](http://us.levi.com/family/index.jsp;jsessionid=vL5TNyqNG0wTRVQDg4nYnFSl6CLmQH4pnyv7Hlx2n1Lv20XvWt2m!1546932027?cp=3146842&clickid=header_big&categoryId=3515596)):

```
<fb:like width="90" layout="button_count" href="http://r.levi.com/product/index.jsp?productId=3672714&amp;r=&amp;c=3" font="arial" ref="FamilyLike:3515596"></fb:like>
```

I'm not up to date on Facebook's FBML (XFBML?) markup syntax, but it looks like the key here is the `href` which is unique per product.  That `ref` attribute also appears to be useful.

[According to Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/):

- **href** - the URL to like. The XFBML version defaults to the current page.
- **ref** - a label for tracking referrals; must be less than 50 characters and can contain alphanumeric characters and some punctuation (currently +/=-.:_). The ref attribute causes two parameters to be added to the referrer URL when a user clicks a link from a stream story about a Like action:

  - **fb_ref** - the ref parameter
  - **fb_source** - the stream type ('home', 'profile', 'search', 'other') in which the click occurred and the story type ('oneline' or 'multiline'), concatenated with an underscore.

I think the biggest difference to notice here is that the desired functionality is implemented using the [Facebook markup](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/#xfbml) and [JavaScript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/), as opposed to the simpler `iframe` method.  The additional functionality requires a bit of additional development work, though not much.

Answer (score 1):

The HREF attribute needs to be unique for each "like".

Answer (score 0):

did you check this?

[facebook developers forum post](http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=344747#p344747)